# Remove the database exception error on a page reload

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am on Django Framework and implemented an interface where a user can do Insert and Update operations on a MySQL table.

MySQL student table does not allow duplicate entries, so if a user enters a duplicate key an Exception message is displayed. If, a user re-submits a successful query to the database the error message disappears.

**What is the current issue:**

- If a user tries to reload the page after a bad query was sent to the database  the error message is still displayed. On a page reload it returns a POST request, so it's submitting the duplicate entry again triggering the Exception

How can I stop this request from being submitting again on a page reload, since it seems on a page reload it re-submits the duplicate entry?

**views.py**

```
def generate_student_info(request):

    # Retrieve inputted value
    current_student_name = request.POST.get('student_name')
    current_student_id = request.POST.get('student_id')

    # Read the table from the database
    connection = db.open_connection(read_only=False)
    sql_str = f"""SELECT * FROM {students_table};"""
    df = db.read(sql_statement=sql_str, connection=connection)

    # creating a formset
    insert_formset = formset_factory(StudentInfoForm, extra=0)
    formset = insert_formset(request.POST or None, initial=[{'student_id': df['student_id'][i], 'student_name': df['student_name'][i]} for i in range(len(df))])

    context = {'formset': formset, 'db_error_message': '', 'display_error_message': False}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Insert MySQL query
        if 'student_name' in request.POST:
            try:
                insert_query = f"""INSERT INTO {students_table} (student_id, student_name) VALUES ({current_student_id},'{current_student_name}');"""
            db.write(sql_statement=insert_query, connection=connection)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/student_info/")

        except Exception as e:
            context['db_error_message'] = e
            context['display_error_message'] = True
            print(e)
            return render(request, 'student_info_table.html', context)

        # Update MySQL query
        else:
            if formset.is_valid():
                for form in formset:
                    if form.has_changed():
                        print(form.cleaned_data)
                        try:
                            update_query = f"""UPDATE {students_table} SET student_name='{form.cleaned_data['student_name']}' WHERE student_id='{form.cleaned_data['student_id']}';"""
                            db.write(sql_statement=update_query, connection=connection)
                            return HttpResponseRedirect("/student_info/")

                        except Exception as e:
                            context['db_error_message'] = e
                            context['display_error_message'] = True
                            print(e)
                            return render(request, 'student_info_table.html', context)
            else:
                print('formset is not valid')

    context = {'formset': formset, 'db_error_message': '', 'display_error_message': False}

    return render(request, 'student_info_table.html', context)
```

**student_info_table.html**

```html
<form action='' method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Insert" id="id_insert" class="generate">
    </div>
</form>

{% if display_error_message %}
  <h4>{{db_error_message}}</h4>
{% endif %}

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="insertion-formset">
  <table>...</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending error message through context use django messages framework. It was built to achieve what you want. To use this you send message from views as

```
messages.error(request, 'Display error message.')
```

You can also add multiple message for the request. It is also removed when page is reloaded. Check out [document here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/)

Comment: Thanks for the response this fixed my issue! The link you provided did not work on my end, but I used this link for reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Glad that it solved your issue . I messed up while adding a link and didn't double check. Now I have also fixed the link.